# ActiveAdmin - Static Content on Index Page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, activeadmin

I am trying to do map based filtering on an ActiveAdmin data set.  I have created  a partial that contains my Map and associated Javascript, and I can render it using this code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Location do
  menu priority: 4, label: 'Locations'

  filter :name
....


  index do

    panel "Maps" do
      div do
        render :partial => "/admin/dashboard/map", :locals => {  }
      end
    end

....
```

However, if the filters are set on the page such that there is no data meeting the criteria for the data set - then no content is shown and my map is not shown.  The idea here is to allow filtering based on the map, which I have working, but when there is no results, I still want the map to show so the user can alter the map settings and find the data they want.

Does anyone know how to do this in ActiveAdmin?  Basically I want a partial to show no matter what the result set is for this particular index.

Thanks in advance!